# [Object][Object] Error Sharepoint Power App Table

Tags: sharepoint, powerapps, powerapps-formula, powerapps-collection

I have the following error when inserting a Table into Power App.

[image]

The reason is that Composition is a choices Column and so is effectively a table within a cell.

[image]

Looking online there do appear to be workarounds but I am struggling to get this to work for my desired table.

1. https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/object-Object-Powerapps-and-Sharepoint-list/td-p/172007
   The suggestion here is to add a column which somehow for each item displays the record.

My attempt at this:

```
AddColumns('QSAR Analysis Submission Data'[@Composition], "newcolumn", ThisRecord.Composition)
```

But this just returns a similar result only specific to Composition now:

[image]

2. https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/DataTable-is-showing-object-Object-in-column-for-data-from/td-p/137040

[image]

Again this attempt fails.

```
ClearCollect('QSAR Analysis Submission Data', AddColumns('QSAR Analysis Submission Data'[@Composition], "newcolumn", ThisRecord.Composition))
```

Comment: I’m checking how the things are going on about this issue. Whether the answer helps you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using single selection choice column, use:

```
AddColumns('QSAR Analysis Submission Data'[@Composition], "newColumn", ThisItem.Composition.Value)
```

For multiple selection choice column, try using formula like this:

```
AddColumns('QSAR Analysis Submission Data'[@Composition], "newColumn", Concat(ThisItem.Composition, Value & ", "))
```

**Reference**: [SharePoint List Multi-choice column in Data table showing error](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/SharePoint-List-Multi-choice-column-in-Datatable-showing-error/td-p/370403?wt.mc_id=MVP_315224)

Comment: Hi there, Would I be able to reach out to you about your blog post here?

https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2022/10/08/add-an-image-to-sharepoint-image-columns-using-power-automate/

Comment: Hi @Nick, which blog post exactly?

Comment: Add an image to SharePoint Image columns using Power Automate. 

I shall be posting a question shortly

Comment: Sure, you can post it on SharePoint StackExchange: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions

Comment: Ah I just posted here actually: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78088303/powerautomate-flow-to-add-image-to-image-metadata

Let me know if you want me to move it over

Answer (score 1):

As per your shared screenshot (first one), you seem to have missed the `Value` attribute in the `Text` property of your column. Since you are trying to pull data from a choice type column, you need to specify the attribute which you need to pull/show from you choice column attributes (as in the backend choice column return many attributes in json/table form when to try to read/access it and in your case you need the `Value` property out of it)

Try changing the `Text` property of your **Composition** column to:

```
ThisItem.Composition.Value
```

And similarly add `.Value` on the other column's `Text` property wherever it is a choice column.